# Translate query to NHibernate

Tags: sql, nhibernate

I am trying to learn NHibernate, and am having difficulty translating a SQL query into one using the criteria API.

The data model has tables: Part (Id, Name, ...), Order (Id, PartId, Qty), Shipment (Id, PartId, Qty)

For all the parts I want to find the total quantity ordered and the total quantity shipped.  In SQL I have:

```
select shipment.part_id, sum(shipment.quantity), sum(order.quantity)  
  from shipment cross join order
  on order.part_id = shipment.part_id
  group by shipment.part_id
```

Alternatively:

```
select id, 
   (select sum(quantity) from shipment where part_id = part.id), 
   (select sum(quantity) from order where part_id = part.id)
  from part
```

But the latter query takes over twice as long to execute.

Any suggestions on how to create these queries in (fluent) NHibernate?  I have all the tables mapped and loading/saving/etc the entities works fine.

Comment: unless you have one-to-one relations on order-shipment then those two queries could render different results because if an order has two shipments, then that order would be counted twice in the aggregation in the first example.

Comment: I would consider re-thinking that data model.  Or, since you are using ORM, start with an object oriented approach and auto gen the DB.

Answer (score 2):

Well - I don't really get the whole idea of your model - but maybe this criteria will work for you. Otherwise check the NHibernate documentation for [criteria APIs Section Projections, aggregation and grouping](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-projection).

```
List results = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Shipment))
    .CreateAlias("Order", order)
    .SetProjection (Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add (Projections.GroupProperty("id"), "id)
        .Add (Projections.Sum ("Quantity"), "shipmentQuantity)
        .Add (Projections.Sum ("order.Quantity"), "orderQuantity)
    ).List();
```